# For loop is executing on multiple divs at a time, instead of applying it one by one on div

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom-manipulation, random-effects

I am creating randomly fading squares on the image. They end up one by one partially revealing the image. This function was meant to hide random squares one by one but it is hiding them abnormally.

```
setInterval(disappearingBoxes, 500);

function disappearingBoxes() {
  for (let i = 0; i < boxes.children.length; i++) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toFixed()
    if (!boxes.children[i].classList.contains('hidden') && boxes.children[i].id === i) {     
      boxes.children[i].removeAttribute('id');      
      if (boxes.children[i].getAttribute('id') === null) {
        boxes.children[i].classList.add('hidden') 
      } else {
        let newI = Number(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toFixed());
        boxes.children[newI].classList.add('hidden')    
      }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function disappearingBoxes() {
  for (let i = 0; i < boxes.children.length; i++) {
    if (!boxes.children[i].classList.contains('hidden') && boxes.children[i].id === i) {     
      boxes.children[i].removeAttribute('id');      
      if (boxes.children[i].getAttribute('id') === null) {
        boxes.children[i].classList.add('hidden') 
      } else {
        let newI = Number(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toFixed());
        boxes.children[newI].classList.add('hidden')    
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the same as before, still squares disappearing abnormally